# Uploading preview video to app store connect shows this error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a preview video to app store connect and getting the following extremely useless error. Has anyone seen this before who'd be able to provide any insight into why I'm getting this?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the video resolution and format? Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@reefwing/ios-app-screenshots-and-previews-for-itunes-connect-a5813bb1c47c)

Comment: @Rod did you find solution to your issue? I am having the same issue and my format is mp4, Codec H264 and resolution is the same as apple recommended 886X1920, in fact I am having same issue with other screen sizes

Comment: Yeah we went back to the company who did the videos for us and they recoded it to Apple's standards and it worked. Beyond that we didn't have to change anything else so I'm not sure if I can be much help, unfortunately